# Estimating hidden rating in games

Tags: model, hidden-markov-model, latent-variable, games, elo

There are a number of online games (e.g. Overwatch, League of Legends) that use a hidden rating system thats designed to be an estimate of your "true" skill level, and is used to match you with/against other players of a similar ability.

The player only has access to their actual skill rating, which is often different from their hidden skill rating. But in addition to actual skill rating, players also see other stats that might be indicative of their hidden rating. This might include things like actual skill rating of your team and your enemies, as the system will presumably match you with people of a similar hidden skill rating. The amount of actual skill rating you gain/lose after a match is presumably a function of the hidden rating value of all players

I'm wondering if there are any statistical techniques that will allow you to estimate what that hidden rating value is?

There are ways to model the *relationships* between visible stats and hidden skill rating. For example, we could maybe model the hidden value as a latent construct and estimate relationships that way

Is there a way to estimate the actual hidden value, when we dont have a starting point for its value? There are models like hidden markov models that allow for unknown mid-states, but I'm not sure that theres any direct value estimation in those types of models

Comment: I don't see how statistics could approach this question without some model or hypothesis or notion of *how* the hidden score is related to observable quantities. You need to start somewhere.

Comment: so we could model the how using something like latent variables. obviously it wont be perfect because we have imperfect information. but once youve established the relationships, would it then be fair to calculate values for those latent variables as a crude estimate of the hidden value? I guess I'm trying to think outside the box and see if theres an idea/method that might get close to solving this type of problem, even if its not perfect

Comment: Even in a latent-variable model, you need to make assumptions (or consider a family of hypotheses) about how the latent variable is related to observables.